# Selenium - Finding WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

```
<div class="hasGoals">
     <a class="ppS"> 1 </a>
     <a class="ppS"> 2 </a>   *
     <a class="ppT"> End </a>
<div class="hasGoals">
     <a class="ppS"> 3 </a>
     <a class="ppS"> 4 </a>
     <a class="ppT"> End2 </a>
```

How can I get the marked (*) element by writing `driver.findElement()...`

This didn't work :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='hasGoals']//a[@class='ppT']"))
```

I think this pattern is true but there are 2 div classes which have same class name.Can it be the reason of the problem ? How can I handle with it ?

Comment: On an html page you can get element by multiple ways: by xpath, by cssselector ... Give it a try not asking a question too general like this. If you got trouble then asking here

Comment: @TuyenNguyen I tried it but I couldn't figure out how i can do this , i tried xpath but it didn't work.

Comment: If you have already tried, then post what you have tried and what is wrong with your approach to get help

Comment: @TuyenNguyen I updated it with more html source code and the code that I have already tried thank you for you suggestions

Comment: Can you give full html page? I need to check if your xpath is correct or not

Comment: @TuyenNguyen I can't share it here sorry but thanks for your effort , I'll try to figure out what's happening

Comment: That's ok. A tip for you: open your html page in chrome => right click on your element choose inspect element => on the element html show up, right click => copy => xpath. By that way you can get correct xpath instead of get it by hand

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the element that you want is not unique except in the text that it contains. There are 4 `A` tags that contain the class `ppS` so that won't get you the right element, so we have to rely on contained text. In order to get an element by contained text, we have to use XPath. The XPath below should work.

```
//a[@class='ppS'][.='2']
```

You could throw this in a function and reuse it.

```
public void selectGoal(String s)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ppS'][.='" + s + "']");
}
```

Since you want the element that contains "2", you would call it like

```
selectGoal("2");
```

NOTE: this function will not select the elements `End` or `End2` because they are a different class, `ppT` instead of `ppS`.